# Generation of Extension interfaces

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, extension-attributes, code-generation

What is the code that generates the `ExtensionInterface` suffixed classes ?

For example, there is this file that declares extension attribute on the product options (and others). `Magento/Catalog/etc/extension_attributes.xml`.

Here is a sample if it.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ProductOptionInterface">
        <attribute code="custom_options" type="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CustomOptionInterface[]" />
    </extension_attributes>
    ....
</config>
```

This declaration will add the methods `getCustomOptions` and `getCustomOptions` in the autogenrated interface `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductOptionExtensionInterface` and in the implementation of this class `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductOptionExtension` (both located in the `generated/code` folder).

My question is simple. What is the code that reads the `extension_attributes.xml` files and generates the interfaces and classes?

(PS. I don't want an explanation on how to add my own attributes).